# Integer.parseInt() method crashes with an empty string as the parameter

Tags: java, android

https://youtu.be/LsKjw-IJQpI Hello everyone I have a question I was following a tutorial and I have a problem when I press the button and when it is empty edittext my application says stoped I wanted to know how to solve it?

```
this is the code



 buttonalarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonalarm);
    buttonalarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int hour = Integer.parseInt(houredit.getText().toString());
            int minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteedit.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
            intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);

            if (hour <= 24 && minute <= 60) {
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });
```

and my logcat

```
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.koko.myapp.alarma$2.onClick(alarma.java:72)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: this is a vague description of what happens. do you get an error message? does it stop as in a regular shutdown, or crash? have you debugged your code?

Answer (score 2):

This line is throwing the `NumberFormatException`:

```
Integer.parseInt(houredit.getText().toString());
```

Because `houredit.getText().toString()` return an **empty string** and you can't parse empty String into Integer.

Before you parse check that the `houredit.getText().toString()` don't return with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the current answers didn't seem to have multiple answers or examples of how to fix it. The reason why you are getting this is because it is getting a `NumberFormatException` and because the string is empty it can't parse it and crashes, so there are two ways you can fix it.

The first way would be to check to see if the string is empty and if not then follow through with the parsing of the data.

```
if (!houredit.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
 int hour = Integer.parseInt(houredit.getText().toString());
 int minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteedit.getText().toString());
 Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
 intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
 intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);

 if (hour <= 24 && minute <= 60) {
   startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

The second way would be with a `try/catch`, which tells the app to try something and if it can't do it throw an error.

```
try{
 int hour = Integer.parseInt(houredit.getText().toString());
 int minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteedit.getText().toString());
 Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
 intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, hour);
 intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, minute);

 if (hour <= 24 && minute <= 60) {
   startActivity(intent);
 }
}catch(Exception ignored){} // <- capture exception if you need, else you can ignore it
```